# Mix columns in CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file and I need to mix 2 of its columns:

```
Sitio, ID_espacio, Espacio, Tamano, Country, Impresiones_exchange, Importe_a_cobrar, eCPM, Subastas, Fill_rate
NUEVO_Infotechnology, 264244, NUEVO_Infotechnology - Home_IT - IT_Header, Variable (1240x90), Bangladesh, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 1, 0.00
NUEVO Apertura, 274837, NUEVO Apertura - Nota_Ap - Right3_300x250, 300x250, Paises Bajos, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 4, 0.00
```

The problem is I need to mix `ID_espacio`with `Espacio` but in this way:

example:

```
NUEVO_Infotechnology, 264244, NUEVO_Infotechnology - Home_IT - IT_Header, Variable (1240x90), Bangladesh, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 1, 0.00
```

What I need:

```
NUEVO_Infotechnology, 264244 - Home_IT - IT_Header, Variable (1240x90), Bangladesh, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 1, 0.00
```

As you can see I remove the first name of the `Espacio` until the '-' and then i put the `ID_espacio`.

I tried to do it and I could but the now I need to have all the csv and not only my modification:

```
import csv

lista_ok = []
base = []

with open("test.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

for item in your_list[1:]:
    a = item[2].split(" - ")
    base.append(a)

for item in base:
    for itemf in your_list[1:]:
        b = []
        a = itemf[1] + ' - ' + ' - '.join(item[1:])
        b.append(a)
        lista_ok.append(b)
```

Output:

```
[[' 264244 - Home_IT - IT_Header'], [' 274837 - Home_IT - IT_Header'], [' 264244 - Nota_Ap - Right3_300x250'], [' 274837 - Nota_Ap - Right3_300x250']]
```

Output I need:

```
[['Sitio', ' ID_espacio', ' Espacio', ' Tamano', ' Country', ' Impresiones_exchange', ' Importe_a_cobrar', ' eCPM', ' Subastas', ' Fill_rate'], ['NUEVO_Infotechnology', ' 264244 - Home_IT - IT_Header', ' Variable (1240x90)', ' Bangladesh', ' 0', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 1', ' 0.00'], ['NUEVO Apertura', ' 274837 - Nota_Ap - Right3_300x250', ' 300x250', ' Paises Bajos', ' 0', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 4', ' 0.00']]
```

Comment: _output I need_ ... don't you want to remove ID_espacio, it no longer matches the following rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here another version:

```
import csv

lista_ok = []

with open("test.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

for item in your_list:
    sitio = item[0]
    id_espacio = item[1]
    item.remove(id_espacio)
    espacio_parts = item[1].split(' - ')
    if your_list.index(item) > 0:
        espacio_parts[0] = espacio_parts[0].lstrip().replace(sitio,id_espacio)
        espacio = ' - '.join(espacio_parts)
        item[1] = espacio
    lista_ok.append(item)
```

Comment: It has an error. Because I need to remplace only the first part of the '-' not all the row

Comment: Hello Martin, I changed it a little bit. Just try it and let me know if it works this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that transforms a single row the way you want. Then call that function for each row as you read it from the file and put it in your final list:

```
def row_transform(row, is_header=False):
    if not is_header:
        # trim Sitio from Espacio
        row[2] = row[2].split(" - ", 1)[1]
        # add ID to espacio
        row[2] = " - ".join((row[1], espacio))
    # remove ID col
    del row[1]
    return row

with open("test.csv") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    lista_ok = [row_transform(next(reader), True)]
    lista_ok.extend((row_transform(row) for row in reader))
```

Comment: I can't understand where you open the csv file??

Comment: After defining `row_transform` I have a module level `with open(..)` that opens the csv. This is done the opposite of your code. First I define a function that does the dirty work then I write the code that reads and processes the data.

Comment: ...and `lista_ok.extend()` is where most of the work is done. `(row_transform(row) for row in reader)` is an iterator that takes each row in reader, calls the function and returns its result as its own iteration. Extend takes all of the transformed rows coming out of the iterator and adds them to the list.